# how to get git log without the commit message

Tags: git, bash, terminal, git-bash

I want to get the `git log` only with the no of `additions` and `deletions`without the `author`, `date`,`commit hash` and the `commit message` details, for identifying how many lines of codes have been modified. 
Currently I am being able to remove all the above except the `commit message` by using the following `bash` command

```
git log origin/master --numstat --since="2 weeks ago"  --no-merges | egrep -v 'Author|Date|commit
```

The output of the above is as follows

> Adding test case for IDENTITY-3591
>
> 4 0   modules/integration/tests-common/admin-clients/pom.xml
>   129   0   modules/integration/tests-common/admin-clients/src/main/java/org/wso2/identity/integration/common/clients/challenge/questions/mgt/ChallengeQuestionMgtAdminClient.java
>   223   0   modules/integration/tests-integration/tests-backend/src/test/java/org/wso2/identity/integration/test/challenge/questions/mgt/ChallengeQuestionManagementAdminServiceTestCase.java
>   2 0   modules/integration/tests-integration/tests-backend/src/test/resources/testng.xml
>   5 0   pom.xml
>
> Updating SAML metadata version
>
> 10    10  modules/p2-profile-gen/pom.xml 2    2   pom.xml
>
> Updating dependency versions
>
> 4 4   pom.xml
>
> Changing value of the version tag in carbon.xml to be picked from the project version
>
> 1 0   modules/distribution/pom.xml
>
> Fixing carbon.identity.auth.version name
>
> 1 1   pom.xml
>
> Downgrading identity.data.publisher.oauth.version to avoid test failures
>
> 1 1   pom.xml
>
> Update dependencies to latest versions.
>
> 10    8   pom.xml
>
> Adding dependencies for each version property to be used by maven version plugin.
>
> 29    28  modules/p2-profile-gen/pom.xml 175  4   pom.xml

How can I get the output without the `commit message`? Thanks in advance

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question, perse, but would have saved me time...i didn't want long commit messages in my code output:`git log -p --format=short` ... in a nutshell `--format` has some built-in's (`oneline`, `short`, `medium`, `full`, `fuller`, `reference`, `email`, `raw`).  `short` was what removed the long commit msg for me.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can do:

```
$ git log --stat --format="%H"
```

You can customize it as you needed. Here

```
$ git log --pretty=format:"%h %ad- %s [%an]"

Here:
- %ad = author date
- %an = author name
- %h = commit hash (short)
- %H = commit hash (full)
- %s = subject
- %d = ref names
```

[Git's pretty docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats#Documentation/pretty-formats.txt-emnem) lists all placeholders.

Comment: nope it does not work, it further adds the `commit hash` value in front of the `commit` message :(

Comment: this is what I was looking for `git log --pretty=format:"%H" ` which gives me only the full commit hash

Comment: As @KasunSiyambalapitiya says, this logs the commit hash that the OP asked not to have. In addition, the format of each line is completely different, and possibly unsuitable for a pipe.

Answer (score 18):

Try this

```
git log --numstat --format=
```

Comment: please provide a complete answer

Comment: @KasunSiyambalapitiya this is the correct answer. The format argument acts like a filter, so setting an empty value suppresses all output.

Comment: This is the correct answer, I needed almost exactly what the OP asked for, and this eliminates everything except what I need to see.