# git log patch without commit message

Tags: git

I am using 'git log -p' to get the git patches. How to print the patch without the commit messages.

```
Author: abc
Date:   Tue Apr 1 23:46:39 2013 +0000
  I don't want commit message

diff --git 
..............
...........
--- /dev/null
+++
```

Expected:

```
Date:   Tue Apr 1 23:46:39 2013 +0000

diff --git 
..............
...........
--- /dev/null
+++
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like `git log -p --pretty='format:Date: %aD%n'` to specify a pretty format that includes just the date. If you also want the object ID, you can write  `git log -p --pretty='format:commit %H%nDate: %aD%n'`

If you're only interested in processing a single patch, you can also use the following

```
git format-patch --stdout HEAD^..HEAD | sed -n '/^Date:/p;/^diff --git/,$p'
```

You can do more advanced things with Perl or Ruby instead of sed if you want, which will allow you to process more patches.

Answer (score 0):

```sh
git log -p --format=
```

displays the patch without any part of the commit message. Similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40837380/1959808